# Inequality with Euclidean norm and dot product

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I want to prove the following, that for $||x|| = \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^2\bigg)^\frac{1}{2}$, it is true that

$$\|x\|=\sup \{|x \cdot y|: y \in \Bbb{R^n} \text{ and } ||y||=1\} $$

This is supposed to come via Cauchy Schwartz. The sup with (!) an equality is really disorienting me.

I think I must rewrite y in some way. Maybe $\frac{x}{||x||}$? Then it would have norm $1$. Any nudges greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, you can see that
$$|x\cdot y|^2 \leq \|x\|^2\|y\|^2$$

Obviously, when $\|y\|=1$, we have that $|x\cdot y|^2 \leq \|x\|^2$. Hence, $|x\cdot y| \leq \|x\|$ for any $y$ such that $\|y\|=1$. Therefore,

$$\sup \{|x \cdot y|: y \in \Bbb{R^n} \text{ and } ||y||=1\} \leq \|x\|$$

Also, taking $y_{\star}=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ shows that the supremum is actually attained at $y_{\star}$ and therefore it's equal to $\|x\|$. This is why:

$$|x\cdot y_{\star}|=\bigg| x \cdot \bigg(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\bigg)\bigg|=\frac{|x \cdot x|}{\|x\|}=\frac{\|x\|^2}{\|x\|}=\|x\|$$